# iOS app confusing careers ads

Tags: bug, status-declined, jobs, ios-app, ios-app-feed

This "Java Script" job advert is currently on my feed:
[image]

Which, when tapped, takes me through to this C# job.

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/94104/c-sharp-developer-crisp-thinking?utm_source=mobile-feed&utm_medium=ad&utm_campaign=mobile-feed-mobile-feed

[image]

Has been doing it for a couple of days, so I don't think it's a rendering issue - I wondered if perhaps the advert had been renamed or something.

Comment: Since the company is the same, I'm guessing the ad was just renamed.  Once a feed item has been loaded, it stays cached on device so if something is renamed/deleted on SE or Careers your feed won't reflect that.

Comment: @BrianNickel Fair enough. Guess it's a one off then!

Comment: @Chris I also noticed 'Java Script' two words instead of one.

Comment: @Hacker I know. Embarrassing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug on SE side, as Brian [explains in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264562/ios-app-confusing-careers-ads#comment861032_264562):

> Since the company is the same, I'm guessing the ad was just renamed. Once a feed item has been loaded, it stays cached on device so if something is renamed/deleted on SE or Careers your feed won't reflect that.

Hence, fix is declined.